# Proof: If a matrix is semi-definite and symmetric positive then it is a covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

Anyone have the following proof? If a matrix is semi-definite positive and symmetric then it is a covariance matrix.

Comment: a covariance matrix is a matrix that is a positive semi definite matrix. (any) definiteness can be a property of any matrix. whether a covariance matrix obtains a specific type of definiteness depends on the nature of the data the covariances are being computed for

Comment: it may not be symmetric

Comment: One proof is that (assuming it is symmetric) it is the covariance matrix of the (multivariate) Normal distribution it determines, *qed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.  Consider the [normal random vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) $\mathbf{X} \sim \text{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ with density function:

$$p(\mathbf{x}) = (2 \pi)^{-n/2} \det(\mathbf{\Sigma})^{1/2} \exp \Big( -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x} \Big)
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

The variance/covariance matrix for this random vector is:

$$\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{\Sigma}.$$

(Hat-tip to [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) in the comments for this answer.)